Makeindex mangling multibyte characters
I am getting an error in my log file on the last page of my Index:
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 2679 replaced by U+FFFD.

The index point responsible is generated (by XSLT, from an XML document):
\index{§=\texttt{"§"} (attribute value)}

This is (apparently correctly) creating the entry in my .idx file for page 73:
\indexentry{§=\texttt{"§"} (attribute value)}{73}

The section sign is a symbol on its own, indexed nowhere else, so it's getting an index section all of its own right at the end of the Index (after the Zs).
The result of running makeindex is:
\indexspace
{\bfseries\hfil �\hfil}\nopagebreak

\item \texttt{"§"} (attribute value)\pfill 73

The character between \hfils is visible in my editor as \302 only but the section mark in the \item line is showing in my editor as two bytes \302\247.
The output PDF has the correct line entry:
"§" (attribute value) . . . . . . . . . . . . . 73
but the heading above it just shows the (centered) non-character symbol �. It should of course be bold, but I'm using Noto (noto.sty 2022/09/11) and the NotoSerif-Bold.ttf font does have a bold section sign where expected (U+00A7).
I'm running this in XeLaTeX (XeTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) with LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2 and makeindex version 2.15 [TeX Live 2019]. Yes, old, but the development needs to work for people still using older systems.
I'm not clear why makeindex apparently handles the sign correctly for the index entry line but truncates it to a single byte in the heading (between the \hfils). The section sign  gets typeset correctly everywhere else. This is a UTF-8 document, so the source uses §, not \S.
I could map the sign to \S in the transformation, but is there something I can do to overcome this in makeindex itself?

You can have a look at xindex.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xindex}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

test\index{§@\texttt{"§"} (attribute value)}

\printindex

\end{document}


I don't think it's possible to change @ in the \index argument to =, though.

Thanks, I'll try it. But I don't think the problem is in LaTeX: it's makeindex which is mangling the character from the .idx file to the .ind file.

Yes, the problem is with makeindex, which is why I proposed to use xindex (the program)
